# Can proto2 talk to proto3?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have two applications that talk to eachother via GPB messages. Both were using proto3, but found out one will have to use proto2. If the messages are the same, can one program use proto2 to compile while the other uses proto3? Or do they need to be compiled with the same version of proto.

Comment: Recommend replacing GPB acronym with the full term the first time you use it. After that feel free to use the acronym, but without that first expanded definition you may find your self with answers covering Russian banking, public broadcasting in Georgia (Both the US State and the European Nation), Brazilian Vacations, and a treatise on the Great Britain Pound by some poor, confused soul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wire format is very similar, so it will work to some extent. However, there are some caveats:

- Distinction of `required`/`optional` fields does not exist on proto3. You should make all the fields `optional` on proto2 side to avoid errors about missing required fields.
- When proto3 encodes fields, any fields that have zero value will be missing when decoded on proto2 side. If you specify zero as default value on proto2 side, it should work out ok.
- Extensions and Any type will be quite difficult to use in a way that would be compatible with both.